# error while comparing a QString

Tags: c++, qt

im trying to write a simple loggin form in Qt . its supposed to open another form if the username and password are right .
but its acting really weird 
heres my code :

```
login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    QPushButton * login_button = new QPushButton;
    QPushButton * exit = new QPushButton;
    login_button->setText("LOGIN");
    exit->setText("EXIT");

    QLineEdit * username  = new QLineEdit;
    QLineEdit * password  = new QLineEdit;
    QVBoxLayout * login_layout = new  QVBoxLayout ;
    QHBoxLayout * button_layout = new  QHBoxLayout ;
    username->setText("Enter Username ...");
    password->setText("Enter Password ... ");

    exit->connect(exit,SIGNAL(pressed()),this , SLOT(close()));
    login_layout->addWidget(username);
    login_layout->addWidget(password);

    button_layout->addWidget(login_button);
    button_layout->addWidget(exit);

    login_layout->addLayout(button_layout);
    this->setLayout(login_layout);

    this->connect(login_button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(finduser()));
}

void login::finduser()
{

    if (username->text().compare("admin")) //  <---- problem !!
    emit showmanage() ;

    return;
}
```

finduser is a SLOT for my dialog class . it emits the "showmanage" signal which opens the form im willing to open .
the actual problem is in the if statement . i have no idea why but when it runs it causes my windows to crash .
this also doesnt work :

```
void login::finduser()
{

    if (username->text()=="admin") //  <---- problem !!
    emit showmanage() ;

    return;
}
```

i have no idea what im doing wrong 
also heres the debug message :
the inferior stopped because it recievd a signal from operating system
signal name : sigsegv
signal meaning : segmentation fault

Answer (score 3):

```
QLineEdit * username  = new QLineEdit;
```

Given that you are not getting compilation errors, I assume you have a uninitalised member variable `username`. But in the constructor you declared a new local variable with the same name. The block scoped variable `username` is different from the member variable.

Comment: There is nothing to hate about. I do much worse simpler mistakes :)